# How to delete extended_calendar using Autosys jil

Tags: autosys, jil

I was able to find the JIL syntax/format for the creation of extended_calendars in Autosys. But I couldn't find any syntax to delete any extended calendars.

Can anyone please provide a sample example. Thanks in advance.